# Why does a vector's capacity become equal to it's size after being passed to a function?

Tags: c++, vector, std

As stated in the title, when I pass a vector to another function, its capacity becomes equal to its size at the time of the function call.

```
void sizeCheck(std::vector<int> test)
{
   std::cout << "Size:     " << test.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Capacity: " << test.capacity() << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> test;

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      test.push_back(i);
      std::cout << "Size    : " << test.size() << std::endl;
      std::cout << "Capacity: " << test.capacity() << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }

   test.resize(0);

   for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
      test.push_back(i);
      sizeCheck(test);
   }
}
```

The above code's first series of outputs show that the vector's capacity increases how one could normally expect; however, the second series of outputs is indicating that the size is always equal to the capacity. I'm assuming this means the capacity is being pushed back by one each time.

I understand that normally it would be best to just pass by reference (const or not), but isn't there any circumstance where I would need to pass a copy of a vector and manipulate it in some way without affecting my original data? In this case, passing by value would be inefficient if every time I use push_back, it has to relocate the vector.

Something like

```
v2.assign(v1.first(), v1.end());
func(v2);
```

would work, assuming func() takes a vector by reference, but it seems strange to me that I'm allowed to pass a vector to a function by value if there are zero cases where it's the best option.

Comment: *if there are zero cases where it's the best option* -- Consider this:  Your function takes a vector by const reference, but then inside that function, you make a copy of that vector so that you can work with the temporary copy.  With the advent of move constructors, it is quite feasible that passing a vector by value is faster than passing a vector by const reference and making a copy of it inside the function.

Comment: The `test` in `main` is not the same as the `test` parameter to `sizeCheck`. If you pass `test` by reference, with `void sizeCheck(std::vector<int>& test)`, then they are the same, and you will get different results.

Comment: I would argue that the case in which you have to repeatedly pass large vectors by value and then add more elements to them and eventually throw away the modifications is not common at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ you have the choice of passing **by value**, **by reference**, or **by pointer**, depending on the situation.

You are passing your vector **by value** into the function.  A copy of the vector is being made. The vector copy constructor makes the capacity of the new vector the same as the size of the vector being copied from.

If you pass your vector **by reference** or **by pointer** instead, no copy is made, you output the size/capacity of the original vector instead:

```
void sizeCheck(std::vector<int> &test)
{
   std::cout << "Size:     " << test.size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Capacity: " << test.capacity() << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

```
void sizeCheck(std::vector<int> *test)
{
   std::cout << "Size:     " << test->size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Capacity: " << test->capacity() << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```